# simply connected Lie groups are isomorphic iff locally isomorphic

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, fundamental-groups, diffeomorphism

I am reading a lecture note on Lie groups, and in the note it states that upon "standard topological considerations", two simply connected Lie groups $G,H$ are locally isomorphic if and only if they are isomorphic.

Here two Lie groups $G$ and $H$ are locally isomorphic if there exist open neighborhoods $U\subset G$ and $V\subset H$ of the identity elements $e_{G}$ and $e_H$ and a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ from $U$ onto $V$ such that $\varphi(gh) = \varphi(g)\varphi(h)$ for all $g,h\in U$ such that $gh\in U$.

I am trying to prove the above statement without using Lie algebra machinery but I couldn't find a valid proof, so I am looking for some hint or reference. I attempted to extend the locally defined diffeomorphism $\varphi$ to all of $g\in G$ via paths connecting the identity $e_{G}$ to $g$, but I couldn't show this extension is well-defined (independent of choice of paths connecting $e_{G}$ to $g$).

Comment: It's because a connected simply-connected Lie group is uniquely determined by its Lie algebra, and if the groups are locally isomorphic, their Lie algebra, which is the tangent space at the identity have to be equal.  This is 'heavy machinery'.  It's not simple to prove.  This stuff is covered in any in-depth textbook on Lie groups.